# How to add two datepickers in android?

Tags: android, datepicker

First I had gone through some basic tutorial for android and I tried to do DatePicker application.When I selects date then the selected date will be displayed in the first TextView which is under first DatePicker.It is working fine for me.But I need to add one more DatePicker.When i selects second DatePicker and if i give my selection has done then it changes the first TextView.I need to do the changes in the second TextView.Please do help me to solve this problem.

This is my xml file.

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
android:layout_width="fill_parent"
android:layout_height="fill_parent"
android:orientation="vertical" >

<ScrollView
    android:id="@+id/scrollView1"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:layout_alignParentLeft="true"
    android:layout_alignParentTop="true" >

    <LinearLayout
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="414dp"
        android:layout_alignParentLeft="true"
        android:layout_alignParentTop="true"
        android:layout_marginTop="66dp"
        android:orientation="vertical" >
<Button
    android:id="@+id/btnChangeDate"
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:text="Start Date" />

<TextView
    android:id="@+id/tvDate"
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:text=""
    android:textAppearance="?android:attr/textAppearanceLarge" />

<DatePicker
    android:id="@+id/dpResult"
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content" />

<Button
    android:id="@+id/btnChangeDate1"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:text="End Date" />

 <DatePicker
    android:id="@+id/dpResult1"
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content" />

 <TextView
     android:id="@+id/tvDate1"
     android:layout_width="match_parent"
     android:layout_height="wrap_content"
      />
</LinearLayout>
</ScrollView>
</LinearLayout>
```

This is my activity code.

```
public class MainActivity extends Activity {
private TextView tvDisplayDate,tvDate1;
private DatePicker dpResult,dpResult1;
private Button btnChangeDate,btnChangeDate1;

private int year;
private int month;
private int day;

static final int DATE_DIALOG_ID = 999;

@Override
public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

    setCurrentDateOnView();
    addListenerOnButton();
    setCurrentDateOnView1();
    addListenerOnButton1();

}

// display current date
public void setCurrentDateOnView() {

    tvDisplayDate = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.tvDate);
    dpResult = (DatePicker) findViewById(R.id.dpResult);

    final Calendar c = Calendar.getInstance();
    year = c.get(Calendar.YEAR);
    month = c.get(Calendar.MONTH);
    day = c.get(Calendar.DAY_OF_MONTH);

    // set current date into textview
    tvDisplayDate.setText(new StringBuilder()
        // Month is 0 based, just add 1
        .append(month + 1).append("-").append(day).append("-")
        .append(year).append(" "));

    // set current date into datepicker
    dpResult.init(year, month, day, null);

}

public void addListenerOnButton() {

    btnChangeDate = (Button) findViewById(R.id.btnChangeDate);

    btnChangeDate.setOnClickListener(new OnClickListener() {

        @Override
        public void onClick(View v) {

            showDialog(DATE_DIALOG_ID);

        }

    });

}

public void setCurrentDateOnView1() {

    tvDate1 = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.tvDate);
    dpResult1 = (DatePicker) findViewById(R.id.dpResult1);

    final Calendar c = Calendar.getInstance();
    year = c.get(Calendar.YEAR);
    month = c.get(Calendar.MONTH);
    day = c.get(Calendar.DAY_OF_MONTH);

    // set current date into textview
    tvDate1.setText(new StringBuilder()
        // Month is 0 based, just add 1
        .append(month + 1).append("-").append(day).append("-")
        .append(year).append(" "));

    // set current date into datepicker
    dpResult1.init(year, month, day, null);

}

public void addListenerOnButton1() {

    btnChangeDate1 = (Button) findViewById(R.id.btnChangeDate1);

    btnChangeDate1.setOnClickListener(new OnClickListener() {

        @Override
        public void onClick(View v) {

            showDialog(DATE_DIALOG_ID);

        }

    });

}

@Override
protected Dialog onCreateDialog(int id) {
    switch (id) { 
    case DATE_DIALOG_ID:
       // set date picker as current date
       return new DatePickerDialog(this, datePickerListener, 
                     year, month,day);
    }
    return null;
}

private DatePickerDialog.OnDateSetListener datePickerListener 
            = new DatePickerDialog.OnDateSetListener() {

    // when dialog box is closed, below method will be called.
    public void onDateSet(DatePicker view, int selectedYear,
            int selectedMonth, int selectedDay) {
        year = selectedYear;
        month = selectedMonth;
        day = selectedDay;

        // set selected date into textview
        tvDisplayDate.setText(new StringBuilder().append(month + 1)
           .append("-").append(day).append("-").append(year)
           .append(" "));

        // set selected date into datepicker also
        dpResult.init(year, month, day, null);

    }
};
```

Thanks in advance.

Comment: change textview id   tvDate1 = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.tvDate1);

Answer (score 0, accepted):

add another dialog id like:

`static final int DATE_DIALOG_ID_2 = 998;`

and include your second button  like:

`tvDisplayDate1 = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.tvDate1);`

then on your second button do this:

```
  btnChangeDate1.setOnClickListener(new OnClickListener() {

            @Override
            public void onClick(View v) {

                showDialog(DATE_DIALOG_ID_2 );

            }

        });
```

then:

```
 protected Dialog onCreateDialog(int id) {
    switch (id) { 
    case DATE_DIALOG_ID:
       // set date picker as current date
       return new DatePickerDialog(this, datePickerListener, 
                     year, month,day);
      case DATE_DIALOG_ID_2:
       // set date picker as current date
       return new DatePickerDialog(this, datePickerListener2, 
                     year, month,day);

    }
    return null;
}
```

then

```
private DatePickerDialog.OnDateSetListener datePickerListener2 
            = new DatePickerDialog.OnDateSetListener() {

public void onDateSet(DatePicker view, int selectedYear,
        int selectedMonth, int selectedDay) {
    year = selectedYear;
    month = selectedMonth;
    day = selectedDay;

    // set selected date into textview
    tvDisplayDate1.setText(new StringBuilder().append(month + 1)
       .append("-").append(day).append("-").append(year)
       .append(" "));

    // set selected date into datepicker also
    dpResult1.init(year, month, day, null);

}
};
```

Hope this helps

Answer (score 0):

See your line `tvDate1 = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.tvDate);` in this function `public void setCurrentDateOnView1()`

You create a variable `tvdate` but you use the id of the first `TextView` so change this

```
tvDate1 = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.tvDate);
```

to

```
tvDate1 = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.tvDate1);
```

**EDIT**

You have only one listener and he use the variable `tvDisplayDate`. So is set the date in the first `TextView`. You need to use 2 listener and not the same for both.

Comment: Yes I corrected that line.  Still the date is changing in first textview